# Run a .sh file in Azure Cosmos DB with MongoDB using Azure Devops CI/CD pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I want to run a .sh file stored in my repository on Azure Cosmos DB with MongoDB through Azure Devops CI/CD pipeline everytime the pipeline is run

I went through the tasks already suggested in Azure CI/CD pipeline but couldn't find a task that is relevant to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Typically `.sh` would be a shell/bash script so a bash task would be best.

In Azure pipelines YAML:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: path/to/your/script.sh
```

Comment: If it helps, you could accept it as answer ,  it could help other community members who get the same issues .